# Does Adding more neural units reduce the probability of trapping in a local minima?

Tags: neural-networks, backpropagation

Consider a multi-layer neural network that learns its weights with backpropagation (and gradient descent). Hence, there is a probability that we trap into a local minimum.

Will adding more neural units solve the problem?

Comment: the way to avoid local minima is by using momentum Read this for more information http://www.willamette.edu/~gorr/classes/cs449/momrate.html

Comment: You can see from [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/203300/103153) that "recovering the global minimum becomes harder as the network size increases".

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you will definitely avoid local minima with more neurons. Adding more neurons increases the volume of your solution space exponentially, but at the same time increases the amount of equivalent solutions factorially.

Comment: I would expect the opposite. As an extreme counter-example, consider the case where you only have 1 neuron. Then, you can always find the global optimum.

Comment: What guarantee do you have that this 1-dimensional function is going to be convex?

Comment: What I had in mind is a network that consists of a single neuron which can be optimized with the perceptron algorithm.

Comment: The question is about gradient descent.

Comment: this is interesting. have you got any reference?